# FFmpeg works on CMD but gives error with PHP exec()

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos

When i run ffmpeg on cmd it works good, i put `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` into /etc/profile.d because it couldn't fine libmp3lame at the first

[image]

But when i run it with PHP exec() it still gives `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libmp3lame.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

```
$exec_string = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -version 2>&1';
echo exec($exec_string);
```

Why it works on cmd but not on php exec() ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured. Here is the solution

```
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib");
```